# How to connect to Ubuntu Server using external IP

Tags: dns, home-server, dyndns

I do not have a static IP because my external rarely changes. How can I connect via SSH and FTP via an external IP address.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use any of the [Dynamic DNS services](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS) available. This way, you could use a "static" URL when connecting using a SSH / SFTP client.

The most common way to use dynamic DNS on Ubuntu is using [ddclient](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ddclient) [image: Install ddclient].

The community documentation has some information about [how to configure `ddclient`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS#ddclient).